# How to convert min to hours?

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I'm trying to make a simple app.I have a value in minute that I want to display in a label in HH(Hours) format, I have JSON dictionary,  i want to get in this minute values inside JSON dictionary. so how to convert it minute to hours formate .

[image]

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: if let con  = country["charge_per_min"]  as? Int {
                        print("++++++ \(con ) ++++")
                        
                        self.chargperMin.append(con)
                        print(self.chargperMin)
                
                    }
charge_per_min my json paramiter..what can i do now..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067949/how-to-convert-min-to-hours-in-swift3   please check my new question i have implenebt this question. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067949/how-to-convert-min-to-hours-in-swift3 pls check - Raptor