# Get double hours from double minute in Swift 2

Tags: swift, date, swift2

I'm using Swift 2. I have `double myMinute` and I want to convert it to `double hours(myHours)`. How can I do it? My codes under below

```
let myMinute : Double = 62.0
let myHours  : Double = ?
```

I want to show with math example: myhours = 1.0

Comment: sorry don't understant but  1 min = 0.016666666h so to get hour = Double((myMinute *  0.016666666)) will give your hours

Comment: It's a simple division. One hour has 60 minutes.

Comment: print(myMinute/60) ?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri dude output is 0.183333333333333  wrong

Comment: @vadian yeah simple but i want to show output 1.0 , dont 1.02

Comment: Do you mean you want it rounded to 1 decimal place always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067949/how-to-convert-min-to-hours-in-swift3)!

```
func minutesToHoursMinutes (minutes : Int) -> (hours : Int , leftMinutes : Int {
return (minutes / 60, (minutes % 60)) 
}

let timeTuple = minutesToHoursMinutes(minutes: 100)

timeTuple.hours  /// 1
timeTuple.leftMinutes /// 40
```

Comment: dude output must be like , 1.02

Comment: @Daniel Lyon output is example 3.723432434, how can i do it only 3.7 ?

Comment: let roundedHours = Double(String(format: "%.1f", myHours)) @SwiftDeveloper

Comment: I see in this answer you temporarily modified the code, though I don't understand the purpose of so many consecutive rollbacks. If you want to use the expanded version, feel free - it is in [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51552439/revisions). Also, the addition of some introductory/explanatory text as to why this answer solves the problem would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The value should be 1.03 not 1.02 if you use the current value of minute (you can check with calculator) and it is a simple math, i think what you want beside the calculation is how to round the value to 2 decimal point. You should've made it clearer. This will do the work.

```
myHours = Double(round(myMinute / 60 * 100) / 100)
print(myHours)
```